# Hero on Tab behavior after flutter version upgrade

Tags: flutter

After upgrading Flutter from 1.7.8 (I have tested 1.9.1 and 1.10.2), there is some strange behavior of hero for me... I have hero image on the main page. On the second/detail page  I have two tabs, first with hero, second empty.

(GoBack)From the first tab hero animation is working as expected, but (GoBack) from the second empty tab, image on the first page disappears. Is this expected behavior in newer versions?

[After some testing this hero tab behavior is from ˆ1.9.0 version, last ok 1.8.4]

Test code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Hero Test'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Hero(
              tag: "hero",
              child: Image.network("https://dummyimage.com/200x200/ff0329/fff"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage()),
          );
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DetailPageState createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Second Route"),
          bottom: TabBar(controller: _tabController, tabs: [
            Tab(text: "1"),
            Tab(text: "2"),
          ])),
      body: TabBarView(controller: _tabController, children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Hero(
              tag: "hero",
              child: Image.network("https://dummyimage.com/200x200/ff0329/fff"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Text(""),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: am not fully sure but try ```_controller.dispose()``` on your state ```dispose``` method .

Comment: ... you are right, I forgot dispose _tabController in sample code, but it has no effect on described behavior

Answer (score 1):

Bug... fixed in version v1.9.1+hotfix.6

more info https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40239